# c++ Class containing vectors of other Classes

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to make a program that has "Class University" that contains a vector for "class Department" [vector  Departments]. Inside of the "class Department" under public I have two constructors and a print function.

In my University.cpp, I am trying to make a function that adds a new object Department and puts it into the vector Departments in "University". I believe I am doing this wrong because I am trying to call the constructor for Department() in the University function and I am getting this error message:

```
$ g++ University.cpp
/usr/li`enter code here`b/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/cc6XExwc.o: In function `University::CreateNewDepartment(std::string, std::string, long)':
University.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `Department::Department(std::string, std::string, long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Class Departments has the following private variables (long id, string name, string location, long chairID). Do I need to use a set() function to create the object, and if so how would I go about doing this?

University.h below

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


#include "Person.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Faculty.h"
#include "Department.h"
#include "Course.h"

class University
{

 protected:
  vector<Department> Departments;
  vector<Student> Students;
  vector<Course> Courses;
  vector<Faculty> Faculties;


 public:
  University();
  ~University();

  bool CreateNewDepartment(string depName, string depLoc, long depChairId);
```

University.cpp below

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


#include "University.h"

bool University::CreateNewDepartment (string n, string l, long c)
{
  if ( (c != 0) && (!validFaculty (c) ))
    return false;

  Department D (n, l, c);

   Departments.push_back (D);

  return true;
}
```

Department.h

```
#ifndef DEPARTMENT_H
#define DEPARTMENT_H


#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Department
{
  friend class University;
 protected:
  long id;
  string name;
  string location;
  long chairId;
  static long nextDepartId;

 public:
  Department();
  Department(string n, string l, long c);
  void Print() const;
};
#endif
```

Department.cpp

```
#include "Department.h"
using namespace std;
#include <string>

long Department::nextDepartId;

Department::Department()
{
id = chairId = 0;
name = location = " ";
}

Department::Department(string n, string l, long c)
{
name = n;
location = l;
chairId = c;
}

void Department::Print() const
{
cout << "Name:     " << name << endl;
cout << "Id:       " << id << endl;
cout << "Location: " << location << endl;
cout << "Chair id: " << chairId << endl;
}
```

Comment: This error complains about missing main function not about your logic. You need to include all source files

Comment: I understand the first half of the error is for missing a main. I am wondering how I can create a new object Department in bool University::CreateNewDepartment (string, string long) and have it go into the vector.

Comment: Included all the code used to help with this confusion.

Comment: `g++ University.cpp` --> `g++ University.cpp Department.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments by @SteveHolodnak and @M.M., you have two undefined reference problems here.

1. No main function.
2. Undefined reference to `Department::Department()`

Using `g++ main.cpp University.cpp Department.cpp` where `main.cpp` is your file with your main function should solve all your problems.

Comment: I was forgetting to also compile Department.cpp
If you could also help me with two more questions, how do I make the constructor for the University class. And how would I late change a variable in department, say change the name?

Comment: To change a name in the department, you either need to have the name be a public data member, or have a public "setter" i.e. `void Department::setName(string n) { this->name = n;}`

Comment: Another couple quick notes on style: all of your include statements and `using namespace std;` should be kept in your `.h` files. The only include in `department.cpp`, for example, should be `include "department.h"`

Comment: Thanks for the help, and one last question. I have another class called Student and one of it's variables is a vector<Course> Courses. How would I in University.cpp set a course to go into the vector of class Student? I'll fix up the using and include statements in my .cpp files. I wasn't sure why it wasn't compiling at first so I added them all to see if they would make a difference.

Comment: You'll need to do something similar to what I showed above with changing the name--a function as a part of the Student class that takes in a Course, then adds it to the vector. I'm purposely not giving it to you word for word, because I think you'll benefit from trying to figure it out.

Comment: Would it be something like this? (assuming i is the vector element for the student.
 Students[i].Courses.size() to find the size of the vector, and then Students[i].Courses.push_back(C) to put something into the vector?

Comment: Yes, that would work! As long as `Courses` was a public member of Student. However, many would say that it is "better coding practice" to instead have a member function `void Student::addCourse(Course c) { this->Courses.push_back(c); }` and then do `Students[i].addCourse(c)`.